# Bundle simple JS for node with Vite

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm trying to bundle a simple JS file with Vite for node.

Here's my `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        target: 'node18',
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'index.js'),
            fileName: 'index',
            formats: ['cjs'],
        },
    },
})
```

And my `index.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

async function main() {
    const { status } = await axios.get('https://google.com')
    console.log(status)
}

main()
```

Then, when I run `node dist/index.js` after building it with Vite (`npx vite build`) I get the following exception:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

It seems the `target: 'node18'` has no effect in the `vite.config.js`.

I was able to run the same script with webpack, but I'd love to use Vite instead.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using using the vite-node package instead of vite ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-node

Comment: Indeed, running `npx vite-node index.js` seems to work!